# Managing "this" in event/callback driven JavaScript applications

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js

I was wondering what is the intended method for dealing with "this" references in callbacks frequently used in frameworks like jQuery and Backbone.js

Here is the simplified example I'm having a problem with, using Backbone.js and jQuery UI, but it is not really specific to these frameworks.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
   render: function() {
      $('#mybutton').click(function() {
         // My code in here
      });
   },

   callMe: function() {
      alert('Rawr!');
   }
});
```

Now, how would I go about referencing the instance of MyView from inside the click handler? For example, how would I call "callMe" from inside the click handler? Outside the handler I'd just call this.callMe(); but "this" gets replaced with the DOM element inside the click handler. What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: have you tried MyView.callMe ?

Comment: @Bogdan Emil Mariesan: it won't be an instance call

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most effective way is simply to store the result of `this` in another variable, and then use that within the callback;

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
   render: function() {
      var that = this;

      $('#mybutton').click(function() {
          // use that for MyView and this for the DOM element
      });
   },

   callMe: function() {
      alert('Rawr!');
   }
});
```

Alternately, you can use either [`jQuery.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy) or the HTML 5 ([beware of backwards compatability](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/#reserved-words-note)) [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method to define the value of `this`. Obviously then you'd loose the ability to use `this` to refer to the DOM element, so would have to rely on the `target` property of the `Event` object;

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
   render: function() {
      $('#mybutton').click((function(e) {
          // Use `this` for MyView and `e.target` for the DOM element
      }).bind(this));
   },

   callMe: function() {
      alert('Rawr!');
   }
});
```

Or:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
   render: function() {
      $('#mybutton').click(jQuery.proxy(function(e) {
          // Use `this` for MyView and `e.target` for the DOM element
      }, this));
   },

   callMe: function() {
      alert('Rawr!');
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the jQuery proxy method. I was originally using the var that = this; but it seemed a bit "hacky".

Comment: Just to add something: As a rule of thumb, creating a variable is best when callbacks can nest (since lexical scoping covers that for you). Using proxy and bind is best when you can't or don't want to rewrite the function that is using the "this".

Comment: @Tomdarkness: I'd like to stress that in this situation, most seasoned developers would *expect* the `var that = this` approach.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it. The `events` attributes is an easy way to have most of your event handlers listed in one location. `_.bindAll(this)` will make it so `this` references the view inside all of the `MyView` functions.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
   events: {
     'click #mybutton': 'clickHandler'
   },
   initialize: function() {
     _.bindAll(this);
   }
   render: function() {

   },
   clickHandler: function() {
     this.callMe();
   },
   callMe: function() {
      alert('Rawr!');
   }
});
```