# Submit form event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, event-handling, form-submit

I develop the first backbone RESTfull application. I have the following view:

```
var app = app || {};

app.AssessorsCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#assessors',
    tagName: 'table',

    events:{
        "submit form": "searchAssessors"
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new app.AssessorsCollection();
        this.collection.fetch({reset: true, data: $.param({ online: false}) });
        this.render();

        this.listenTo( this.collection, 'reset', this.render );
    },

    render: function() { /// },

    renderRegion: function( item ) { /// },

    searchAssessors: function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.collection.remove();

        console.log("EVENT");
    }
});
```

This is my HTML Form:

```
<form id="form-search-assessors" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    .........

    <input id="search-assessors-button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Search" />
    <!--<button id="search-assessors-button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit">Search</button>-->
</form>
```

I put breakpoint to searchAssessors, but it does not work. Also, I don't see any messages in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of my problem:

```
$( "form#form-search-assessors" ).submit($.proxy(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this);

    this.collection.fetch({reset: true, data: $.param({ online: true}) });
    this.render();
}, this));
```

The sourse is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9813760/1756750

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the event to `"submit #form-search-assessors": "searchAssessors"`.

Comment: Unfortunately, It does not help for me. My handler does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize the view ?, Since is just a fragment from your code I removed a couple of things and comments, this should work.

Thanks

HTML

```
<div id="assessors">
    <form id="form-search-assessors" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
       <input id="search-assessors-button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit"            value="Search" />
   </form>
<div>
```

JS

```
AssessorsCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({


    el: '#assessors',
    tagName: 'div',

    events:{
        'submit form': 'searchAssessors'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {  },

    searchAssessors: function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('EVENT');
    }

});

view = new AssessorsCollectionView();
```

Comment: yes, I did. I have the file app.js, in which I write: new app.AssessorsCollectionView();

Comment: Unfortunately, div assessors does not contains this form. Therefore, your example does not fit for me.

Comment: Actually is not my example, is your example. I tried to give a little bit of structure to provide some help, since it won't work as it is, you have thinks like renderRegion: function( item ) { /// }, that will produce an error. Here is the example working if you want to take a look. http://jsfiddle.net/arturo_pst/4vz1ogw9/4/

Comment: Unfortunately, It does not work, because tag assessors does not contain form form-search-assessors.

Comment: So, you are trying to add events to elements outside of the view(el) ?

Comment: Yep, now I am trying to do this things.